# AWK Command to Add values

Tags: unix

I have a scenario where I am trying to add three fields in a line, that I receive it in my input file. I have written something which I felt doesn't follow the best unix practice and need some suggestions how to write the best possible. Attached my sample line.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to add all three fields using one awk command?
2. The input file may not contain some of these fields ( basaed on scenarios), is awk able handle this? Should I do any check ?
3. Some time the values may contain "~" at the end , how to consider only numeric?

Input File1 Sample Line

```
CLP*4304096*20181231*BH*0*AH>444*158330.97~*FB*0*SS>02*0*SS>03*0*J1*0~
```

Input File2 sample line

```
CLP*4304096*20181231*BH*0*AH>444*158330.97*FB*0
```

Script I have written

```
 clp=$(awk -F'[*]' '/CLP/{print $7}' $file)
 ss02=$(awk -F'[*]' '/CLP/{print $11}' $file)
 ss03=$(awk -F'[*]' '/CLP/{print $13}' $file)
 clpsum=clp+ss02+ss03
```

I know it's not the best way, pls let me know how can I handle both the input file 1 ( it has 158330.97~) scenario and file 2 scenario.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in 1 awk command:

`awk 'BEGIN{FS="*"}{var1=$7;var2=$11;var3=$13; var4=var1+var2+var3; printf("var4 = %.2f\n",var4)}' file.txt`

works as long as fields are the same ~ you might want someone with a more robust answer if you want to handle whenever a file comes in with numbers in different fields ~etc. Hope this helps in anyway.

Comment: thank you, but i couldn't get my conditions fulfilled..  It failed for step 2 & step 3... """""""The input file may not contain some of these fields ( basaed on scenarios), is awk able handle this? Should I do any check ?
Some time the values may contain "~" at the end , how to consider only numeric?"""""

Comment: There's many things to be asked, for example: are the fields you want to add always the same? So fields 7,11,13? The fact the data might not always have a fixed 15 fields makes this a lot more complex. It would be a lot easier if it had always 15 fields and some of the fields just empty. I'd recommend if you could get somehow get in touch with Ed Morton https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton he might be able to help you :)